# AWS lambda has missing arguments when invoked from curl, but not when invoked from the lambda console

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, curl, aws-lambda

I have a lambda that is defined like this:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type Input struct {
    AccountId      string `json:"account_id"`
    Server         string `json:"server"`
    Character      string `json:"character"`
    SavedVariables string `json:"saved_variables"`
}

func Handler(ctx context.Context, args Input) (string, error) {
    fmt.Println("logging from lambda")

    // Log lambda input.
    fmt.Println("pre marshal")
    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(args, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal lambda input: %w", err))
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("input: %s\n", string(b))
    }
    fmt.Println("post marshal")

    return "hello", nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

When I invoke it with the below event json from the lambda console,

```json
{
  "account_id": "12345678#1",
  "server": "Mock Server",
  "character": "Mockchar",
  "saved_variables": "mock saved variables"
}
```

the lambda finishes executing successfully and I can see logs like the following in CloudWatch:

```
2022-08-20T18:19:45.092+00:00   input: {
2022-08-20T18:19:45.092+00:00   "account_id": "12345678#1",
2022-08-20T18:19:45.092+00:00   "server": "Mock Server",
2022-08-20T18:19:45.092+00:00   "character": "Mockchar",
2022-08-20T18:19:45.092+00:00   "saved_variables": "mock saved variables"
2022-08-20T18:19:45.092+00:00   }
```

When I instead invoke the exact same lambda with the below curl request,

```
curl -X POST \
    'https://REDACTED.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{"account_id": "12345678#1", "server": "Mock Server", "character": "Mockchar", "saved_variables": "mock saved variables"}'
```

the lambda too finishes successfully, but in CloudWatch I can see that the arguments specified in the curl request were not received by the lambda:

```
2022-08-20T18:06:57.610+00:00   input: {
2022-08-20T18:06:57.610+00:00   "account_id": "",
2022-08-20T18:06:57.610+00:00   "server": "",
2022-08-20T18:06:57.610+00:00   "character": "",
2022-08-20T18:06:57.610+00:00   "saved_variables": ""
2022-08-20T18:06:57.610+00:00   }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong when invoking the lambda using curl?

*Update*

Changing the type of the lambda input to `interface{}` and logging it when invoking the lambda from curl reveals that it has the below structure:

```
2022-08-21T05:24:43.357+00:00   map[body:{
2022-08-21T05:24:43.357+00:00   "account_id": "12345678#1",
2022-08-21T05:24:43.357+00:00   "server": "Mock Server",
2022-08-21T05:24:43.357+00:00   "character": "Mockchar",
2022-08-21T05:24:43.357+00:00   "saved_variables": "mock saved variables"
2022-08-21T05:24:43.357+00:00   } headers:map[accept:*/* content-length:159 content-type:application/json host:REDACTED.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws user-agent:curl/7.64.1 REDACTED
```

Comment: Are you using proxy integration?

Comment: It's the other way around. You're doing something wrong with the test event in the Lambda console, not with curl. Specifically, your test event doesn't actually match the format of the event that you would receive when the Lambda function is triggered. Debug print the actual event parameter (you've called it `args`) received from a *real* invocation of the Lambda function. Then create a test event that matches that format.

Comment: I have updated the post to include what the event looks like. I am yet to figure how to unmarshal it into a Go struct.

Comment: JSON deserialize the body of the event.

Comment: @Darnock - you added an 'Update' at the bottom, where did you change 'lambda input to interface{}'?

Comment: @Darnock - search under my name, I got an answer to this question